# Swift: Add border to one side of a table View cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewcelleditcontrol

How Can I add a gray border color to the right side of my custom cells in table view?
I have a custom cells of my table and want to add border color to all of it but in on the right side only to indicate that it is possible to swipe right,
Here is my custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class AdminCustomCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var MainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var BackView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var Km: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.BackView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.BackView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.BackView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.BackView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.MainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.18
    self.MainView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    self.MainView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
    self.MainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.MainView.layer.masksToBounds = false
}

//@IBOutlet weak var ParkingView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Alert: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Logos: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ParkingView: UIView!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    ParkingView.frame = ParkingView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using CALayer or override `drawRect` and draw a line where you want.

Here is an example using CALayer

```
private func addRightBorder() {
    let border = CALayer()
    
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 5
    
    // Set the color your want
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    // Create a rect only on the right of the view
    border.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.maxX - borderWidth,
                          y: 0,
                          width: borderWidth,
                          height: bounds.maxY)
    
    layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

**Update**

Based on Duncan's valid comments:

> Note that if your app supports device rotation (or iPad multitasking),
> you need to add logic that detects layout changes and moves the border
> layer. Thus for a full implementation you'll probably need to save the
> border layer as an instance var and add code to adjust its position on
> layout changes.

Here are some changes that hopefully handle this scenario:

```
// Persist the CALayer
var rightBorder: CALayer?

let borderWidth: CGFloat = 5

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    // Add right border if we haven't already
    if rightBorder == nil {
        addRightBorder()
    }
    
    // Update the frames based on the current bounds
    rightBorder?.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.maxX - borderWidth,
                                y: 0,
                                width: borderWidth,
                                height: bounds.maxY)
}

private func addRightBorder() {
    rightBorder = CALayer()
    
    rightBorder!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    layer.addSublayer(rightBorder!)
}
```

Comment: Note that if your app supports device rotation (or iPad multitasking), you need to add logic that detects layout changes and moves the border layer. Thus for a full implementation you'll probably need to save the border layer as an instance var and add code to adjust its position on layout changes.

Comment: @DuncanC - that is a good point. What if I used autolayout instead of frames, I think that would work with any orientation as well then ?

Comment: The problem is layout changes when the app is running (think device rotation). You need to have code that updates your layers when the layout changes, since layers don't know about AutoLayout.

Comment: @DuncanC - thanks for your feedback, added an update that hopefully resolves the shortcomings you highlighted with my first solution.